# Selecting a matching ID from a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

Okay so i have a list filled with objects which have the following properties:

**category_id** and **category_title**

In the code it looks like this:

```
class CategoryModel
{
    public int category_id { get; private set; }
    public string category_title { get; private set; }

    //Constructor
    public CategoryModel(int id, string title)
    {
        category_id = id;
        category_title = title;
    }
```

I have multiple objects of this class stored in a list

```
    static List<CategoryModel> CategoryList = new List<CategoryModel>();
```

From this list i am trying to select the **category_title** where it matches a certain **category_id**

```
    public static string GetCategoryName(int categoryNumber)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> title = from c in CategoryList
                    where c.category_id.Equals(categoryNumber)
                    select c.category_title;
        return title.ToString();
    }
```

So let's say GetCategoryName(4), it's now supposed to select from the list where **category_id** equals 4 and return **category_title**

However it seems that i'm not getting the name back but a syntax of the query instead!

Output: *system.linq.enumerable.whereselectlistiterator'2[project.CategoryModel,System.string]*

Comment: You should include the exact text of the error.

Comment: You're calling ToString() on a list of strings, use string.join to get the items as a single string with each item seperated by a character, if you think about it what is a list of strings as a single string supposed to look like?

Comment: return string.Join(", ", title);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Linq to do it:

```
return CategoryList.Single(c => c.category_id == categoryNumber).category_title;
```

Single will throw an exception if the category list does not have any matching ID.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use code that you _know_ won't throw an exception? See my answer.

Comment: it's depend if you want to mange yourself or not that kind of things. If you want to do it yourself, you should juste change my Linq method by "return CategoryList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.category_id == categoryNumber)?.category_title;". After that you will be able to check if the string is empty or not

Answer (score 2):

Your query returns list not a single category.

Please try this

```
public static string GetCategoryName(int categoryNumber)
{
    IEnumerable<string> title = from c in CategoryList
                where c.category_id.Equals(categoryNumber)
                select c.category_title;
    return title.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The IEnumerable class does not implement some sort of fancy format of its elements in the ToString function. I think the simplest way to approach this would be to use the `String.Join` function if there are supposed to be multiple results:

```
return String.Join(",", title);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Linq to select first or default value :

```
public static string GetCategoryName(int categoryNumber) {
    return CategoryList.FirstOrDefault( category => category.category_id == categoryNumber).category_title;
}
```

But this can throw exception when there's no such category id because of `.category_title` so the best solution would be :

```
public static string GetCategoryName(int categoryNumber) {
    CategoryModel category = CategoryList.FirstOrDefault( category => category.category_id == categoryNumber);
    return category == null ? string.Empty : category.category_title;
}
```

Which will return empty string when no such category was found.

About the error you're getting back. It is because your query returns "many" objects of `CategoryModel` ie. `IEnumerable<string>` which then you try to convert to string.

Doing `ToString()` on any kind of table ( array, list, etc. ) will return something like `system.string[]` or in other words same result as you would do call `IEnumerable<string> .ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetCategoryName(int categoryNumber)
{
    CategoryModel result = CategoryList.Where(x => x.category_id == categoryNumber).FirstOrDefault();
    if (result != null)
        return result.category_name;
    else
        //no matches, do something else
}
```

This will take the item from `CategoryList` where the `category_id` matches the number you passed in, and return category_name if there was a match.

Answer (score 0):

You're ToString'ing the Enumerable, which hasn't been evaluated, which is why you're getting the query implementation object.

Assuming you're after the only item that matches, do:

```
title.SingleOrDefault()?.ToString()
```

*NOTE: the `?` operator will only work on C# 6; you can just do a normal assignment and `if x == null` type check for below*

Comment: @m.rogalski oops, so I did!